# Do you need to re-build a ReactJS app if you want to configure for a different environment

Tags: reactjs, npm

We have an app that is deployed to an Azure Web App

It's a create-react-app project.

My question is, when wanting to configure for a particular environment eg. API URLs, do you need to replace the env file and run "yarn build" again?

I am noticing that certain fields such as process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL are getting baked when building so I am thinking that a re-build is needed when needing to re-configure.

Is there a better way to pull configuration in a react app that doesn't require a re-build?

Comment: If you're using `REACT_APP_` env vars to do that configuration, yes that needs a rebuild. I don't think build-time configuration is a particularly good idea, for reasons I expand on in https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html.

Comment: yes, the environment variables are build-time only. There is a work-around where you can point your start command to a shell script that replaces some placeholder in your `index.html` to the current config.